# Sucking sound from engine!

Tags: noise

Have issues from engine bay every time engine is off just recently.

I started the car, everything is ok. And engine is off. At this point, I could hear a sucking or hissing strange sounds from the engine bay for just 10 seconds approx only. It's just audible when hood is opened.

Everything is ok, all warning signs are checked and ok, all fluids level etc are fine too.

Really worried about this strange sounds. Hope it's not a big issue. Please help.

Comment: Are you using the A/C while running the engine?

Comment: Regardless of AC on or off while engine running, the sound comes just after engine is off...... just like sucking or hissing sound........!!!

Comment: The reason I asked is, if running the A/C while the engine is running, there will be a hissing sound from the A/C refrigerant as it equalizes in the system after the engine is shut off.

Comment: Nope sir....the sound is still heard with AC on or off!!

Answer (score 2):

This could be just systems de-pressurising-i would be worried if its doing it with engine on, in which case a vacuum leak or coolant leak would be present
Best thing is to monitor all fluid levels-and act if check engine light or fluid loss occurs

Comment: Everything is ok, all warning signs are checked and ok, all fluids level etc are fine too.